# Authorize escape character in C# controller

Tags: c#, controller, character

I need to give a string in a endpoint which can contains an escape character like '`\`'.
But I have the following error :

> 'x' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. Path: $.mdpUtilisateur | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 22.

This error is for the value :

```
\xf2d81a260dea8a100dd51798
```

There is the endpoint :

```
 [HttpPost("Login")]
 public ActionResult<UserResponse> Login(UserRequest request)
 {
     UserResponse response = _userService.Login(request);
     if (response == null)
         return NotFound();
     return response;  
 }
```

And the request :

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class UtilisateurConnexionRequest
{

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    [EmailAddress()]
    public string Mail{ get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Password{ get; set; } = string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: That's simply not valid JSON. It's not a matter of "authorizing" it or not - your string simply isn't valid JSON. You should fix whatever is generating it. (If you need to escape a backslash in JSON, you should end up with a double backslash. Are you trying to escape the original string at all? It's very unclear what the client is here...)